# Division on a real quadratic ring of integers.

Tags: ring-theory, algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

I've seen that $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi ] = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}_{\sqrt{5}}}$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio, is a Euclidean domain with norm $N(x + y\varphi ) =  x^{2} + xy - y^{2}$.

Given a particular $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}[\varphi ], b \neq 0$, I want an algorithm(that can be written in code) to find $q, r \in \mathbb{Z}[\varphi ]$ such that $a = qb + r, \; |N(b)|>|N(r)$| or $r = 0$.

Here's what I've come up with so far. If $b =  c + d\varphi$, then let $b' = (c+d)-d\varphi$. It can be shown that $bb' = N(b)$.

If we set $q_{0} = ab'/N(b)$ then we have $a = bq_{0}$, but we have no guarantee that $q_{0}$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi ]$. We need some way of 'rounding' $q_{0}$ to get $q\in\mathbb{Z}[\varphi ]$ so a suitable $r$ falls out. It's this 'rounding' that I don't know how to execute.

Comment: I think in your last paragraph the two occurences of $c$ are supposed to be $a$. Anyway, you have $q_0=s+t\phi$ for some rationals $s,t$. What if you round each rational to the nearest integer, say, $u,v$, respectively, and then let $q=u+v\phi$? Can you show that $r=a-qb$ has small norm?

Comment: The worse-case bound on $|N(r)|$ in this case seems to be at least $|(N(b))|^{2}/4$ with a quick check, not good enough for large $|N(r)|$.

Comment: $a/b=q+\delta$, where $\delta=\epsilon+\eta\phi$, where $|\epsilon|\le1/2$ and $|\eta|\le1/2$. This puts an absolute bound on $N(\delta)$. Then $N(r)=N(\delta)N(b)$. I don't see where you're getting the square of $N(b)$.

Comment: The problem is the coefficients of your proposed $\delta$ are fractions with denominator $N(b)$. There's no guarantee that $r=b\delta$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi ]$. You need to multiply by $N(b)$ at least for that to be the case.

Comment: $r=a-bq$, so of course it's in ${\bf Z}[\phi]$.

Comment: So are we OK now, del?

Comment: Are you still here, del?

Comment: It's ok, I guess.

Comment: Please see whether you are happy with the answer I have posted, del.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We let $\phi={1+\sqrt5\over2}$.

Given $a,b$ in ${\bf Z}[\phi]$, $b\ne0$, we let $$a/b=q_0= ab'/N(b)=s+t\phi$$ with $s,t$ rational and $b'$ defined as above. We choose integers $u,v$ with $$|s-u|\le1/2{\rm\ and\ }|t-v|\le1/2$$ We let $q=u+v\phi$, so $q\in{\bf Z}[\phi]$, and let $r=a-bq$, so also $r\in{\bf Z}[\phi]$. Also, $$r=a-bq_0+b(q_0-q)=b\bigl((s-u)+(t-v)\phi\bigr)$$Then writing $N$ for the norm we have $$|N(r)|=|N(b)|\bigl|\bigl((s-u)^2+(s-u)(t-v)-(t-v)^2\bigr)\bigr|\le(1/2)|N(b)|$$ (using the trivial estimate $|x^2+xy-y^2|\le1/2$ for $|x|\le1/2$, $|y|\le1/2$ – we could do better, but this is more than good enough to answer the question).

Comment: I think you should be more explicit in how to obtain $q_{0}$(or s and t) in this answer(even if you simply refer to the work shown in the question).

Comment: Better, del42z?

Comment: Recall the '(that can be written in code)' part of my question. Naively dividing a by b to get $q_{0}$ won't bode well as $\mathbb{Z}[\varphi ]$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I posted a way to obtain $q_{0}$ cleanly in the question, but a proper answer would at least reference this.

Comment: Fair enough. Happy now?

Comment: You haven't upvoted, del, and you haven't accepted, so you must still have some uncertainty. What do you need?

Comment: I was just away, sorry.